# How to optimize true states on assignation

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
// Image one : first row
user = ReturnUser(pictureBoxUpOne);
if (user != null)
{
     usersFirstRow.Add(user);
     user = null;
}
// Image two : first row
user = ReturnUser(pictureBoxUpTwo);
if (user != null)
{
     usersFirstRow.Add(user);
     user = null;
}
```

That is repeating several times for each image I have. So I was wondering it there is some way to avoid doing the part of:

```
if (user != null)
```

and in the same line where I do

```
usersFirstRow.Add(user);
```

add it only if it's not null, like optimized **ifs**.

Comment: The bigger question is, why is the variable being re-used? :( That would entirely eliminate the extra assignment of null. If there are "many" such operations (say, more than 2), then a Collection-based approach should be used.

Comment: Of course you can. But what are pictureBoxUpOne and pictureBoxTwo, windows components?

Comment: Why are you setting `user = null;` before the second call to `ReturnUser`?

Comment: Actually I'm going to repeat this code more than twice, and I repeat if because I call ReturnUser() several times with different images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would refactor the code into a function that receives a list of picture boxes.

```
private void MyMethod(List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes)
{
    foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxes)
    {
        var user = ReturnUser(pictureBox);
        if (user != null)
        {
             usersFirstRow.Add(user);
             // This line not needed: user = null; 
        }
    }
}

List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = 
    new List<PictureBox>() { pictureBoxUpOne, pictureBoxUpTwo }

MyMethod(pictureBoxes);
```

Comment: Interesting way... I thikn I'm gonna try this one.

Answer (score 4):

(Just to give LINQ a little voice. Although for *just two* picture boxes I'd likely leave the code similar to as it is - albeit with different variable names to minimize variable re-use and I would eliminate the assignments of null entirely. YMMV.)

```
var pictureBoxes = new [] { pictureBoxUpOne, pictureBoxUpTwo /* etc */ };
userFirtRow.AddRange(pictureBoxes
    .Select(pb => ReturnUser(pb))
    .Where(u => u != null));
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it shows a different way of doing things, but I personally wouldn't use LINQ in that case, just as you said yourself.

Comment: @ken2k Why not using LINQ?

Comment: @Sonhja Personal preferences essentially :) In some cases (for example in this case IMO), I think using LINQ makes the code a little harder to read. Again, that's personal preferences.

Answer (score 2):

With declaring a method you can get lack of theese if statements.

```
private void AddIfNotNull(YourUserObject user)
{
   if (user != null)
   {
       usersFirstRow.Add(user);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the pictureboxes in a list or a container so you can do this:

```
foreach pictureBox in someContainer.ChildControls
{
    var user = ReturnUser(pictureBox);
    if (user != null)
    {
        usersFirstRow.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap it in a function:

```
public void AddUserIfNotNull(User user) {
    if (user != null)
        usersFirstRow.Add(user);
}

// ... then ...
public void IteratePictureBoxesAndAddUsers(List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes) { // <-- feel free to rename
    foreach (PictureBox p in pictureBoxes) {
        AddUserIfNotNull(ReturnUser(p));
    }
}
```

.. then again, I may have completely missed the point of what you're trying to do..